# Redirect from domain1 to domain2 and keep in address bar domain1

Tags: apache, redirect

Is there anyway to redirect from `domain1` to `domain2` and keep in address bar `domain1`?
If this is possible, please give me some hints.

From my tests `.htaccess` don't help me, maybe there is a way of doing it from Apache VirtualHost but I can't figure how until now.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use domain forwarding in your registrar toolbar you can accomplish this.

for example: if you have site1.com and you redirect using domain forwarding and choose the option to not show the new site address (at least there is one for godaddy) then when it redirects to site2.com it will still show site1.com in the address bar.

however something to consider is that if you go to a new page (site2.com/newpage.php) it will still show site1.com in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Not with a HTTP redirect, since that simply asks the browser to fetch the new URL. You could load the content of domain2 from domain1, though.